# Como usar corretamente o "Então"

Tags: gramática, concordância

Vejo que é comum o uso da palavra "Então" no início de uma frase, por exemplo:

> Então, você vem me ver hoje?

Isso está correto?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, está correto.

Nesse caso, "**então**" torna-se uma interjeição, algo muito comum para advérbios como esse. E, como interjeição, é normalmente separada da frase por alguma pontuação.

Muitos dicionários catalogam o termo "**então**" apenas como advérbio, mas seu uso interjectivo é descrito pelos seguintes dicionários:

- [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=ent%C3%A3o)
- [Wikicionário anglófono](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ent%C3%A3o#Interjection).
- [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/entao/).

O mesmo ocorre noutras línguas:

> - **Então,** vamos?
> - **Entonces,** vamos? (Espanhol).
> - **So,** let's go? (Inglês).

Esse uso interjectivo não é exclusividade do advérbio "*então*". Vários outros advérbios também possuem-no, principalmente quando usados sozinho numa frase:

> - **Bem,** suponhamos que isso seja uma caveira.
> - **Por favor,** não conte isso a ninguém.
> - João caiu da bicicleta. — **Também,** ele não sabe pedalar.

Comment: Vejo o Então usado como interjeição em algumas regiões do Brasil. Posso dizer, que no Rio Grande do Sul, é pouco usado.

Comment: No Rio de Janeiro é muito usado.

Comment: "Então, alguém tem alguma sugestão ?"